# Angular Velocity expressed via Euler Angles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-velocity, rigid-body-dynamics

On the top of the fourth page from [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec29.pdf), the author trivially derives the components of angular velocity, expressed via [Euler angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) of the system. I fail to understand how the components of angular velocity were derived. May you please enlighten me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you know about rotation matrices, and so for a sequence rotations about Z-X-Z with angles $\phi$, $\theta$ and $\psi$ repsectively you have

$$ \vec{\omega} = \dot{\phi} \hat{z} + T_1 \left( \dot{\theta} \hat{x} + T_2 \left( \dot{\psi} \hat{z} \right) \right) $$

The logic here is apply a local spin of $\dot{\phi}$, $\dot{\theta}$ and $\dot{\psi}$ on the local axes in the sequence.

1. Apply spin $\dot{\phi}$ about local Z and then rotate by $T_1$
2. Apply spin $\dot{\theta}$ about local X (rotated by $T_1$) and then rotate by $T_2$
3. Apply spin $\dot{\psi}$ about local Z (rotated by $T_1 T_2$).

### Update

There is a way to formally derive the above using the identity $\dot T = \vec\omega \times T$ but it is rather involved for 3 degrees of freedom.

For two degrees of freedom it goes like this. With a rotation matrix $T= T_1 T_2$ (defined as above) the time derivative is

$$ \begin{aligned} \frac{{\rm d} T}{{\rm d} t} & = \dot{T}_1 T_2 + T_1 \dot{T}_2  
\\ & = \left( (\dot{\psi} \hat{z}) \times T_1 \right) T_2 + T_1 \left( (\dot{\theta} \hat{x}) \times T_2 \right)
\\ & = (\dot{\psi} \hat{z}) \times \left(  T_1 T_2 \right) + (T_1 (\dot{\theta} \hat{x})) \times \left( T_1  T_2 \right) 
\\ & = \left(\dot{\psi} \hat{z} + T_1 (\dot{\theta} \hat{x}) \right) \times (T_1 T_2)  
\\ & = \left(\dot{\psi} \hat{z} + T_1 (\dot{\theta} \hat{x}) \right) \times T = \vec{\omega} \times T   \end{aligned} 
\\ \vec{\omega} =  \dot{\psi} \hat{z} + T_1 (\dot{\theta} \hat{x}) $$

using the distributed property $T (\vec{a} \times \vec{b} ) = (T \vec{a}) \times (T \vec{b} )$.

Answer (score 24):

Here's a straightforward but somewhat computational way.  There are two steps. (1) Show how to define the angular velocity vector in terms of rotation matrices. (2) Write a general rotation in terms of Euler angles. (3) Combine (1) and (2) to get an expression for the angular velocity vector in terms of Euler angles.

**Step 1.** Recall that if $\mathbf x(t)$ is the position of any point in a rigid body undergoing rotation, then the motion of this vector is generated by a time-dependent rotation;
\begin{align}
  \mathbf x(t) = R(t)\mathbf x(0)
\end{align}
It follows that the velocity of such a point in the body is
\begin{align}
  \dot{\mathbf x}(t) =\dot R(t)\mathbf x(0) = \dot R(t)R^t(t)\mathbf x(t)
\end{align}
where here, the superscript $t$ denotes transpose, and in the second equality, I have used the first equation and the fact that for rotations, $R^t = R^{-1}$.  If we use this fact again in the form
\begin{align}
  RR^t = I
\end{align}
and differentiate both sides with respect to time, then the right side vanishes, and we get
\begin{align}
  \dot R R^t = -R\dot R^t = -(\dot R R^t)^t
\end{align}
This shows that the matrix $\Omega \equiv\dot R R^t$ is antisymmetric, which means that there are three functions $\omega_x, \omega_y, \omega_z$ for which
\begin{align}
  \Omega = \begin{pmatrix}
          0 & -\omega_z  & \omega_y \\
          \omega_z & 0 & -\omega_x \\
          -\omega_y & \omega_x & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
It turns out that the entries of this matrix are precisely the components of the angular velocity vector $\boldsymbol\omega$.  In fact, in many treatments one often defines
\begin{align}
  \boldsymbol\omega = (\omega_x, \omega_y, \omega_z)
\end{align}
To convince you that this is the right definition of angular velocity, a short computation shows that for any vector $\mathbf x$,
\begin{align}
  \Omega \mathbf x = \boldsymbol\omega\times \mathbf x
\end{align}
So that we recover
\begin{align}
  \dot{\mathbf x} = \boldsymbol\omega\times\mathbf x
\end{align}
from the second equation above, which is a standard expression showing how the angular velocity vector generates the velocities of the points in a rigid body.

There is a subtlety that we need to be careful about however.  The angular velocity components given in the notes to which you link are the components of the angular velocity in a basis rotating with the body.  If we let $\mathbf e_i$ denote a non-rotating basis, adn $\mathbf u_i$ denote the basis rotating with the body, then we have
$$
  \mathbf u_i(t) = R(t) \mathbf e_i
$$
In particular, given any vector $\mathbf w$, we can break such a vector into its components in either basis
$$
  \mathbf w = w_i\mathbf e_i = w_{i,B} \mathbf u_i
$$
so the three-tuple
$$
  \mathbf w_B = w_{i,B} \mathbf e_i
$$
Gives the components of any vector in the body basis.  Note that the components of a vector in the body basis can be obtained from its components in the non-rotating basis as follows.
$$
  \mathbf w_B = R^t\mathbf w
$$
In particular, the components of the angular velocity in the body basis are related to its components in the non-rotating basis by
$$
  \boldsymbol\omega_B = R^t\boldsymbol\omega
$$

**Step 2.**  This is actually already done in the MIT notes to which you linked.  It the last equation on the third page.  In the notation from what I called "step 1," we define the Euler angles as follows in terms of successive rotations that take a vector's components in the non-rotating basis, and give its components in terms of the body basis
$$
  R^t = R_z(\psi)R_x(\phi)R_z(\phi)
$$

**Step 3.** We combine steps 1 and 2 to obtain an expression for $\boldsymbol\omega_B$ which gives the components of the angular velocity in the body basis.  To do this, we first compute $\boldsymbol\omega$ from $\Omega = \dot R R^t$ in terms of Euler angles.  Then we apply $R^t$ to $\boldsymbol\omega$ to get $\boldsymbol\omega_B$.  I actually did this just now using Mathematica, and I obtained precisely the result in your linked notes:
\begin{align}
  \omega_{x,B} &= \dot\phi\sin\theta\sin\psi +\dot\theta\cos\psi\\
  \omega_{y,B} &= \dot\phi\sin\theta\cos\psi - \dot\theta\sin\psi\\
  \omega_{z,B} &= \dot\phi\cos\theta+\dot\psi
\end{align}

Comment: Are you sure in the second equation you mean $\dot{\mathbf x}(t) =\dot R(t)\mathbf x(0) = \dot R(t)R^t(t)\mathbf x(0)$? I would think the second equality looks odd. Maybe you mean $\dot{\mathbf x}(t) =\dot R(t)\mathbf x(0) = \dot R(t)R^t(t)\mathbf x(t)$?

Comment: Also, if you wanted to avoid your method looking too 'computational', maybe instead of taking the components of $\omega$ directly from $\Omega$ you could get $\omega$ from $\Omega$ via applying a Hodge dual operation.

Comment: @namehere Thanks that was most certainly a typo.  Yeah I didn't think discussion of the hodge dual was really appropriate at this level; but that's certainly relevant.  Thanks for the comments.