# Rotation from Goldstein's Classical Mechanics

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rotation, rigid-body-dynamics

I apologize for the ambiguity in my title.
It was rather difficult to figure out what is the most appropriate title for my questions.

My questions come from chapter 4 and chapter 5 of Goldstein, which are both about rotations.

First regards to the paragraph following equation (4.84), which states
$dG_i = a_{ji}dG_j' +da_{ji}G_j'$ where prime coordinates are the body coordinate, and unprimed represents the space coordinate. $a$ represents the transformation matrix from space to body.

The paragraph states

> It is no loss of generality to take the space and body axes as
>   instantaneously coincident at the time t. Components in the two
>   systems will then be the same instantaneously , but differentials will
>   not be the same, since the two systems are revolving relative to each
>   other. Thus, $G'_j=G_j$ but $a_{ji}dG_j' = dG_i'$.

I get its reasoning, except the conclusion. I agree that the differentials are different respect to the two coordinate system, but why does that imply $a_{ji}dG_j' = dG_i'$?

Second question I have comes from chapter 5, where it is stated (in section 1),

> Any difference in the angular velocity vectors at two arbitrary
>   points must lie along the line joining the two points.

Why is that true?

Comment: Related http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/85989/19976

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to first question:

At the instant being considered, the space and body axes are identical, so at that moment the matrix $a$ that relates the two sets of axes is simply the identity matrix.  $dG'$ is a vector, so $a_{ji}dG_j' = dG_i'$ is simply equivalent to the statement that with $I$ the identity matrix and $V$ an arbitrary vector, $IV=V$.

Answer to second question:

Immediately prior to the statement in question, the book has just derived that $(\omega_1 - \omega_2 ) \times R = 0$.  Using one possible definition for the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Definition), that equation is equivalent to $\left\| (\omega_1 - \omega_2 ) \right\| \left\| R \right\| \sin \theta \ n = 0$, where $n$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the plane containing $(\omega_1 - \omega_2 ) $ and $R$, and $\theta$ is the angle between $(\omega_1 - \omega_2 ) $ and $R$.  $n$ is not the null vector, and $R$ is presumed to not be the null vector, so if $(\omega_1 - \omega_2 ) $ is also not the null vector, the only other possible way for that equation to hold is if $\sin \theta = 0$, i.e. $\theta = 0$.  I.e. , $(\omega_1 - \omega_2 )$ must be parallel to $R$, which is what the book means by the sentence in question.

Comment: I have no idea why this answer got a down vote.  The only thing I can think of is that perhaps the answer looks totally wrong because $a_{ji}dG_j'$ doesn't look anything like multiplying a matrix by a vector.  So for the sake of people not following along in Goldstein, I'll point out that Goldstein uses the Einstein summation convention, which does make the above expression equivalent to multiplying a matrix by a vector.

Comment: I do not know the reason for the down-vote. I have read the answer and I think it is helpful. Afterwards, I have checked the relevant parts of Goldstein's book and can acknowledge that the answer is appropriate. So I compensated the down-vote.

Comment: Thank you Red Act, your answer was very helpful! I was not the one that gave you a down vote. I want to give you an up vote, but I apparently need more reputations. Thank you sincerely!