The stupidest question ever on relative kinematics and angular velocity
I am scratching my head on a very basic formula whose meaning escapes my intuition.
On basically all texts of mechanics the following result is derived:
Suppose that a rigid body is moving with respect to a fixed reference system $O(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and let $\omega$ be the vector of his angular velocity. We can retrieve the components of $\omega$ as a function of Euler's angles $\varphi,\theta,\psi$ and their time derivatives, on the body fixed reference frame axes $\Omega(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3)$ as:
$$\omega_{\xi_1}=\dot{\theta}cos\varphi+\dot{\psi}sin\theta sin\varphi$$
$$\omega_{\xi_2}=-\dot{\theta}sin\varphi+\dot{\psi}sin\theta cos\varphi$$
$$\omega_{\xi_3}=\dot{\varphi}+\dot{\psi}cos\theta$$
Now my dumb question is: how can we have non null angular velocity components $\omega_{\xi_1}$,$\omega_{\xi_2}$,$\omega_{\xi_3}$ with respect to the body fixed reference frame if such frame is, by definition, rotating together with the body?
Please explain this like I were five years old as I am in the horrendous situation in which I understood the math procedure to retrieve a formula but I cannot grasp its meaning!
Thanks in advance

This might help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88398/

Does this answer your question? Why is body frame angular velocity nonzero?

This has been asked many times. It's a common confusion. In the past month, I've already answered two such questions.

Related : Angular Velocity via Extrinsic Euler Angles.

thanks a lot @VinalV I understand now
