# Angular acceleration related to a time dependent rotation matrix $R(t)$

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, rotational-kinematics

Let the orientation of a coordinate frame $\{b\}$ w.r.t. a static coordinate frame $\{a\}$ be expressed by a rotation matrix $R_{ab}\in SO(3)$  whose columns represent the coordinates of the unitary axis of $\{b\}$ w.r.t. $\{a\}$. Furthermore, let $R_{ab}$ depend on time $t$ i.e. we have $R_{ab}(t)$.

[It is well known](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/293037/how-to-compute-the-angular-velocity-from-the-angles-of-a-rotation-matrix) that the angular velocity, $\omega_{b}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, of the frame $\{b\}$ w.r.t. the frame $\{a\}$ can be obtained by:

$$ [\omega_b]_{\times} = \dot{R}_{ab}{R_{ab}}^T \label{1}\tag{1}$$
Where $[\cdot]_\times$ represents the anti-symmetric matrix related to $\omega_b$.

However I've not been able to read anywhere a similar expression for the angular velocity $\dot{\omega}_b$. I believe it can be directly obtained by differentiating eq. \ref{1} w.r.t. time i.e.:

$$ [\dot{\omega}_b]_\times = \ddot{R}_{ab}{R_{ab}}^T + \dot{R}_{ab}{\dot{R}_{ab}}^T \label{2}\tag{2}$$
In this way $[\dot{\omega}_b]_\times$ is also an anti-symmetric matrix, something that contradicts the [answer in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216079/second-derivatives-of-rotations/2019666#2019666). Why $\dot{\omega}_b$ should not be computed as eq. \ref{2} ?

Comment: I think that your equation (1) should be $\omega_{ij}= R^{-1}_{ik} \dot R_{kj}= R_{ki}\dot R_{kb}.$ Also the other answer you cite is computing $\ddot R$ rather than $\dot \omega$, so I see no immediate contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the equation in the following form, all expressed on the same basis vectors.

$$ \dot{R} = [\omega \times] R $$

This is used to derive the kinematics of joints where $R = R_1 R_2 \ldots $

Now you can definitely take the time derivative of the above using the chain rule to get

$$ \ddot{R} = [\dot{\omega} \times] R + [\omega \times] \dot{R} =  [\dot{\omega} \times] R + [\omega \times] [\omega\times] R $$

or

$$ [\dot{\omega} \times] =  \ddot{R} R^\top -  [\omega \times] [ \omega\times] R R^\top = \ddot{R} R^\top -  [\omega \times]  [\omega\times] $$

Notice that $[\omega \times]  [\omega\times]$ is a symmetric matrix and $\ddot{R} R^\top$ a general matrix. If the above is valid this means that $\ddot{R} R^\top$ is split into symmetric and anti symmetric parts as follows

$$ \ddot{R} R^\top = \underbrace{[\dot{\omega}\times]}_{\text{skew}} + \underbrace{ [\omega \times][\omega \times]}_{\text{symm}} $$