# How do I approximate an angular acceleration vector from a history of orientations?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, discrete

A rigid body is simulated to move in six degrees of freedom. At every past timestep, I know its displacement vectors $x^{GLOB}$ in the global coordinate frame, as well as 3x3 matrices $R$ that describe a rotation from world global orientation to the body local orientation.
$$
x^{GLOB}_{i-2}=R_{i-2} \times x^{BODY}_{i-2}
$$
$$
x^{GLOB}_{i-1}=R_{i-1} \times x^{BODY}_{i-1}
$$
$$
x^{GLOB}_i=R_i \times x^{BODY}_{i}
$$
I can use the finite difference method to approximate the linear accelerations at timestep $i-1$.
$$
\ddot{x}^{GLOB}_{i-1} \approx \frac{x_{i-2}^{GLOB}-2x_{i-1}^{GLOB}+x_{i}^{GLOB}}{(dt)^2}
$$
I can't figure out what is the analogue for the rotation matrices. I know that the result should be a angular acceleration vector $\alpha^{GLOB}_{i-1}$. The angular velocity vector $\omega^{GLOB}_{i-1}$ I found from the handbook "Intermediate dynamics for engineers" by O'Reilly, as well as [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/429081/rotational-kinematics-and-angular-velocity-vector-transformation).
$$
\omega_{0R}=ax(R^T\dot{R})
$$
Would simply taking a finite difference of the angular velocity give me an acceleration?