# Why is it possible to derive the infinitesimal rotation matrix by small angle approximations?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, coordinate-systems, rotation

I am currently studying dynamics and trying to understand the relation between angular velocity $\omega$ of a rotating frame and the eulerian rotation matrix $\mathbf{R=\mathbf{R}\mathrm{(\psi)\mathbf{R}(\theta)\mathbf{R}(\phi)}}$, which accomplishes the rotation. I found a derivation at MIT:

[MIT Courseware - Kinematics of moving frames](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-017j-design-of-electromechanical-robotic-systems-fall-2009/course-text/MIT2_017JF09_ch09.pdf)

They basically try to find the derivative of $\overrightarrow{x}(t)=\overrightarrow{x}_{0}(t)+\mathbf{R}^{T}\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)$, where

$\overrightarrow{x}(t)$ is a vector in the inertial frame

$\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)$ is a vector in the moving frame and

$\mathbf{R}^{T}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\theta\cos\phi & -\cos\psi\sin\phi+\sin\psi\sin\theta\cos\phi & \sin\psi\sin\phi+\cos\psi\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
\cos\theta\sin\phi & \cos\psi\cos\phi+\sin\psi\sin\theta\sin\phi & -\sin\psi\cos\phi+\cos\psi\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
-\sin\theta & \sin\psi\cos\theta & \cos\psi\cos\theta
\end{array}\right]$

(the above vectors shall be defined as the triple of projections of directed line segments along the coordinate axes)

Now, if the angles of rotation are small, $\mathbf{R}^{T}$ can be approximated as:

$\mathbf{R}^{T}\simeq\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -\delta\phi & \delta\theta\\
\delta\phi & 1 & -\delta\psi\\
-\delta\theta & \delta\psi & 1
\end{array}\right]=\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -\delta\phi & \delta\theta\\
\delta\phi & 0 & -\delta\psi\\
-\delta\theta & \delta\psi & 0
\end{array}\right]}_{\textrm{cross product operator}}+\boldsymbol{I}_{3x3}=\boldsymbol{I}_{3x3}+\delta\overrightarrow{E}\times$

where $\delta\overrightarrow{E}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\delta\psi\\
\delta\theta\\
\delta\phi
\end{array}\right]$

Now the derivative of vector $\overrightarrow{x}(t)$ would be:

$\begin{eqnarray*}
\overrightarrow{x}(t) & = & \overrightarrow{x}_{0}(t)+\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)\\
\overrightarrow{x}(t+\delta t) & = & \overrightarrow{x}_{0}(t)+\delta\overrightarrow{x}_{0}(t)+\mathbf{R}^{T}\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)+\delta\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)\\
 & = & \overrightarrow{x}_{0}(t)+\delta\overrightarrow{x}_{0}(t)+\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)+\delta\overrightarrow{E}\times\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)+\delta\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)\\
\frac{\delta\overrightarrow{x}(t)}{\delta t} & = & \frac{\delta\overrightarrow{x}_{0}(t)}{\delta t}+\frac{\delta\overrightarrow{E}}{\delta t}\times\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)+\frac{\delta\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)}{\delta t}\\
 & = & \frac{\delta\overrightarrow{x}_{0}(t)}{\delta t}+\overrightarrow{\omega}\times\overrightarrow{x}_{b}+\frac{\delta\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)}{\delta t}
\end{eqnarray*}$

Now my question: Why can this small angle approximation be made? Isn't that approximation only valid for small rotations and therefore the derived formula only valid in that case?

I know that there are quite some other people who had problems with this, sadly I didnt understand the explanations I found in the web.

---

edit: I just started to doubt the general validity of the above derivation,
because I compared

$\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\overrightarrow{x}(t)=\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\overrightarrow{x}_{0}(t)+\overrightarrow{\omega}\times\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)+\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)$ (last equation from above)

to

$\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\overrightarrow{x}(t)=\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\overrightarrow{x}_{0}(t)+\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\mathbf{R\cdot}\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)+\mathbf{R}\cdot\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)$,

last of which was derived from $\overrightarrow{x}(t)=\overrightarrow{x}_{0}(t)+\mathbf{R}\cdot\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)$
by applying product rule.

That would mean, that $\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\mathbf{R}=\overrightarrow{\omega}\times$
and $\mathbf{R}=\boldsymbol{I}_{3x3}$, which is wrong, in general.

Applying the above derivation to a real problem I got two different
vectors for $\overrightarrow{\omega}$, one from inspection and another
one from:

$\overrightarrow{\omega}=\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\overrightarrow{E}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\psi\\
\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\theta\\
\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\phi
\end{array}\right]$

That leads to my second question, how can $\overrightarrow{\omega}$
be expressed in terms of the rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}$ in the
general case?

I found a not so general solution to that question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/74014/178832) (the second answer) which
basically says that $\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\overrightarrow{E}\times=\overrightarrow{\omega}\times=\dot{\mathbf{R}}\cdot\mathbf{R}^{T}$.

So now we have three different terms that should be related as following
(but aren't): $\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\overrightarrow{E}\times=\dot{\mathbf{R}}\cdot\mathbf{R}^{T}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\psi\\
\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\theta\\
\frac{\delta}{\delta t}\phi
\end{array}\right]\times=\dot{\mathbf{R}}$

I would love to derive an equation for $\overrightarrow{\omega}$ in
a similar manner, only for the situation of shifted rotating
and inertial frame coordinate vectors: $\overrightarrow{x}(t)=\overrightarrow{x}_{0}(t)+\mathbf{R}\cdot\overrightarrow{x}_{b}(t)$.

Sadly my linear algebra knowledge is somewhat limited. That is why
I would be happy about some further help. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In a time $\delta t$ the rotation angles are supposed to be small too

Comment: Related : [Velocity in a turning reference frame](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/velocity-in-a-turning-reference-frame?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

The derivation you quoted assumes the angles $\psi,\theta,\phi$ depend on time, *i.e.*

$$\begin{cases}\psi=\psi(t)\\\theta=\theta(t)\\\phi=\phi(t)\end{cases}$$

In this case, at the moment $t+\delta t$ you can approximate

$$\begin{cases}\psi(t+\delta t)=\psi(t)+\delta\psi(t)\\\theta(t+\delta t)=\theta(t)+\delta\theta(t)\\\phi(t+\delta t)=\phi(t)+\delta\phi(t)\end{cases}$$

In other words, an infinitesimal increment in time leads to infinitesimal increments of the angles captured by the vector

$$\delta\boldsymbol{E}=\begin{pmatrix}\delta\psi\\\delta\theta\\\delta\phi\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Hmm, I dont think I get it...

Comment: @B.Preiss Do you agree that $\delta\boldsymbol{x}=\delta\boldsymbol{E}\times\boldsymbol{x}$?

Comment: @B.Preiss For small rotation?

Comment: Hmm, I dont think I get it... if I apply what you have written above to my sines and cosines: $\sin(\psi(t+\delta t))=\sin(\psi(t)+\delta\psi(t))=\sin(\psi(t))\cdot\cos(\delta\psi(t))+\cos(\psi(t))\cdot\sin(\delta\psi(t))$. Now, when I apply: $\cos(\delta\psi(t))=0$ still $\cos(\psi(t))\cdot\sin(\delta\psi(t))$ remains. Isn't that term only equal to $\delta\psi(t)$ if $\psi(t)$ is close to $0$?

Comment: "for small rotation": can we assume a small rotation in a general case? Couldn't the angles of a general rotation be significantly bigger than 0?

Comment: @B.Preiss Observe that $$\boldsymbol{x}\left(t+\delta t\right)=R\left(\delta\psi,\delta\theta,\delta\phi\right)\boldsymbol{x}\left(t\right)$$ You only need to rotate by an infinitesimal angle in order to advance $\boldsymbol{x}$ from time $t$ to time $t+\delta t$.