# Calculate angular velocity from rotation matrix

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

I tried to apply the procedure found in this link - [derive angular velocity from infinitesimal rotation matrix by small angle approximation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/374947/) - to calculate
$\omega$ from the rotation matrix $\mathbf{R}^{T}$. The specific
situation, where I tried to do this can be found in the picture below:

[image: relation of angles and bases]

Now in my example the basis of the inertial and moving coordinate
system may be given by the vectors $\overrightarrow{e}_{x}$, $\overrightarrow{e}_{y}$,
$\overrightarrow{e}_{z}$ and $\overrightarrow{e}_{1}(t)$, $\overrightarrow{e}_{2}(t)$,
$\overrightarrow{e}_{3}(t)$ respectively.

Here are the projected views (projected along $\overrightarrow{e}_{x}$
and $\overrightarrow{e}_{z}$) of the basis-vectors, where $\alpha$
($\dot{\alpha}=\Omega$) shall be the angle enclosed by $\overrightarrow{e}_{z}$
and $\overrightarrow{e}_{3}(t)$:

[image: projections of basis vectors]

In the views each vector is noted with its projected length.

The coordinate vectors of any point shall be linked by the Rotation
Matrix $\mathbf{R'}$:

$\underbrace{[\overrightarrow{u}]_{i}}_{\textrm{coordinate vector in inertial frame }}=\mathbf{R'}\cdot\underbrace{[\overrightarrow{u}]_{r}}_{\textrm{coordinate vector in rotating frame }}$

I think $\mathbf{R'}$ would be:

$\mathbf{R'}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0\\
\sin(\theta)\cdot\cos(\alpha) & \cos(\theta)\cdot\cos(\alpha) & \sin(\alpha)\\
-\sin(\theta)\cdot\sin(\alpha) & -\cos(\theta)\cdot\sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha)
\end{array}\right]$.

According to the example I linked above, I can approximate $\mathbf{R'}$
as:

$\mathbf{R'}\simeq\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -\delta \theta & 0\\
\delta \theta & 1 & \delta \alpha\\
0 & -\delta \alpha & 1
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -\delta \theta & 0\\
\delta \theta & 0 & \delta \alpha\\
0 & -\delta \alpha & 0
\end{array}\right]+\boldsymbol{I}_{3x3}=S(\omega)+\boldsymbol{I}_{3x3}=\delta\overrightarrow{E}\times+\boldsymbol{I}_{3x3}$

where $S(\delta \theta,\delta \alpha)$
is a Skewsymmetric Matrix and $\delta \overrightarrow{E}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
-\delta \alpha\\
0\\
\delta \theta
\end{array}\right]$.

Analogous to the example it follows:

$\frac{\delta}{\delta t}[\overrightarrow{u}]_{i}=\frac{\delta}{\delta t}E\times[\overrightarrow{u}]_{r}=\underbrace{\left[\overrightarrow{\omega}_{r}\right]_{i}}_{\textrm{angular velocity of rotating frame expressed in inertial frame}}\times[\overrightarrow{u}]_{r}$.

That means, that $\left[\overrightarrow{\omega}_{r}\right]_{i}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
-\dot{\alpha}\\
0\\
\dot{\theta}
\end{array}\right]$.

That seems to be wrong, because by inspection I get:

$\left[\overrightarrow{\omega}_{r}\right]_{i}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
-\dot{\alpha}\\
\dot{\theta\cdot\sin(\alpha)}\\
\dot{\theta\cdot\cos(\alpha)}
\end{array}\right]\neq\left[\begin{array}{c}
-\dot{\alpha}\\
0\\
\dot{\theta}
\end{array}\right]$.

**Here is my question:** What is wrong?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: What's wrong is that you assumed $\alpha$ is negligibly small. In that limit, you'll get $[-\dot\alpha, \dot\theta \sin\alpha, \dot\theta \cos\alpha] \to [-\dot\alpha, 0, \dot\theta]$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Hi and thank you for the Correction. Should I rather repost my changed question or should I edit it here?

Comment: Please edit it here - once it is edited by you, it will automatically be placed in a review queue where users can decide whether it is now on-topic.

Comment: so, I posted my question here [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/374947/why-is-it-possible-to-derive-the-infinitesimal-rotation-matrix-by-small-angle-ap) as a follow-up. Hope it is better that way!