# Application of angular velocity to Euler angles

Tags: rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

According to a post here [Angular Velocity expressed via Euler Angles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73961) you can express angular velocity from euler angles. If I choose Y-Z-Y as a rotation sequence the expression becomes.

$\theta_r, \theta_p, \theta_y$ = roll, pitch, yaw

$$
\vec{\omega} = \dot{\theta_r} \hat{y} + R_z(\theta_p)( \left( \dot{\theta_p} \hat{z} + R_y(\theta_y) \left( \dot{\theta_y} \hat{y} \right) \right)
$$

which becomes

[image]

according to [this](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-multiply-calculator/%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D0%5C%5C%20%20%5Cdot%7B%5Cleft%5C%7B%5Ctheta_%7Br%7D%5Cright%5C%7D%7D%5C%5C%20%200%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%2B%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7Dd%26-c%260%5C%5C%20%20c%26d%260%5C%5C%20%200%260%261%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%5Cleft(%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D0%5C%5C%20%200%5C%5C%20%20%5Cdot%7B%5Cleft%5C%7B%5Ctheta_%7Bp%7D%5Cright%5C%7D%7D%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%2B%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7Db%260%26a%5C%5C%20%200%261%260%5C%5C%20%20-a%260%26b%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D0%5C%5C%20%20%20%5Cdot%7B%5Cleft%5C%7B%5Ctheta_%7By%7D%5Cright%5C%7D%7D%5C%5C%20%20%200%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D%5Cright))

where

[image]

which does not make sense.

does it make sense and does it still work in this case?

Comment: With Y-Z-Y rotations the angular velocity vector is $$ \vec{\omega} = \dot{\theta_r} \hat{y} + R_y(\theta_r) \left( \dot{\theta_p} \hat{z} + R_z(\theta_p) \left( \dot{\theta_y} \hat{y} \right) \right) $$ I think you misunderstood my answer.

Comment: @ja72 Yeah I did but you misunderstood the order. it is first roll, then pitch, then yaw. Thus the angular velocity becomes

$$
\vec{\omega} = \dot{\theta_y}\hat{y}+R_y(\theta_y)\left(\dot{\theta_p}\hat{z}+R_z(\theta_p)\left(\dot{\theta_r}\hat{y}\right)\right)
$$

which finally evaluates to

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \omega_x \\ \omega_y \\ \omega_z \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} a\dot{\theta_p} - bc\dot{\theta_r} \\ \dot{\theta_y}+d\dot{\theta_r} \\b\dot{\theta_p} + ac\dot{\theta_r} \end{bmatrix}
$$

is this correct? thanks for giving me your time.

Comment: Indeed, but my answer below has the correct order. I don't know what the coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$ ... are so I don't know about your result. Please review my answer and award it if it was helpful.

Comment: @ja72 the coefficients are defined in the main post quite clearly and your answer below has the angles in the wrong order. I already said this. When rotating you first rotate in the Y axis with $\theta_r$ then in Z with $\theta_p$ lastly Y again with $\theta_y$. You wrote them in the reverse order even in your answer.

Comment: Check the comments of my post then. Comments about the answer should be added there and not here.

Comment: @ja72 oh just a quick question. if i did not have a special rotation sequence. like if I were to just use $\omega$ as is. would the rotation sequence be X-Y-Z? Like if I were to graphically represent the angles? like first rotate by X then Y then Z?

Comment: That is a good question. From $\vec{\omega}$ you can extract the rotation axis, but not the rotation angle (because of you need rate × time for angle). If you had a time value then you can extract the 3×3 rotation matrix from the [Rodrigues formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation) $$\mathrm{R} = 1 + (\sin \theta) [\hat{u} \times] + (1-\cos \theta) [\hat{u} \times][\hat{u} \times]$$ with $\theta = \| \vec{\omega} \| t$ and $\hat{u} = \vec{\omega} / \| \vec{\omega} \|$.

Comment: No mate listen you misunderstood. If my angles are on each global world axis. Let's say $\theta_x, \theta_y, \theta_y$ with the rotation sequence X-Y-Z, $\theta_x$ being first. Would $\omega_x = \theta_x$, $\theta_y = \omega_y$ ect?

Comment: Also if that were not the case, what rotation sequence makes it so that $\omega_x=\theta_x$, $\omega_y=\theta_y$ ect.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. Three rotations about globally fixed axes are equivalent to three rotations about local axes _but in reverse order_. So on a riding body, a sequence of _Z-Y-X_ is equivalent to a sequence of _X-Y-Z_ about the world coordinates.

Comment: @ja72 how do i choose rotation sequence so that each component in the angular velocity vector is equal to the time derivative of each euler angle.

Comment: You can't. This can only happen at one instant in time when the rotation matrix is the identity matrix => each Euler angle is zero and the sequence has no repeating axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a Y-Z-Y scheme with a corresponding sequence of rotation angles $\theta_y$, $\theta_p$ and $\theta_r$.

After the first rotation (yaw), the 3×3 orientation matrix $\mathrm{E}_y$ and angular velocity vector $\vec{\omega}_y$ is

$$\begin{aligned}
  \mathrm{E}_y & = \mathrm{rot}(\hat{j}, \theta_y) & \vec{\omega}_y & = \dot{\theta}_y \left(\hat{j}\right)
\end{aligned} \;\tag{1}$$

The above should be self-evident. Now consider the second rotation and the orientation matrix $\mathrm{E}_p$ and angular velocity vector $\vec{\omega}_p$. Since the local axes are rotated by the first rotation we have

$$\begin{aligned}
  \mathrm{E}_p & = \mathrm{E}_y \mathrm{rot}(\hat{k}, \theta_p) & \vec{\omega}_p & = \dot{\theta}_y \left( \hat{j} \right) + \dot{\theta}_p \left( \mathrm{E}_y  \hat{k} \right)
\end{aligned} \;\tag{2}$$

Finally, with the third rotation we extend this pattern to find the final orientation matrix $\mathrm{E}$ and the final rotation velocity vector $\vec{\omega}$

$$\begin{aligned}
  \mathrm{E} & = \mathrm{E}_p \mathrm{rot}(\hat{j}, \theta_r) & \vec{\omega} & = \dot{\theta}_y \left( \hat{j} \right) + \dot{\theta}_p \left( \mathrm{E}_y  \hat{k} \right) + \dot{\theta}_r \left( \mathrm{E}_p  \hat{j}  \right)
\end{aligned} \;\tag{3}$$

The last part is re-written as

$$\begin{aligned}
  \mathrm{E} & =\mathrm{rot}(\hat{j}, \theta_y)\mathrm{rot}(\hat{k}, \theta_p) \mathrm{rot}(\hat{j}, \theta_r) & \vec{\omega} & = \dot{\theta}_y  \hat{j}  +   \mathrm{rot}(\hat{j}, \theta_y) \left( \hat{k} \dot{\theta}_p  +   \mathrm{rot}(\hat{k}, \theta_p)  \hat{j}  \dot{\theta}_r  \right)
\end{aligned} \;\tag{4}$$

This expands out to the following jacobian formulation

$$ \vec{\omega} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & \sin(\theta_y) & -\sin(\theta_p)\cos(\theta_y) \\
 1 & 0 & \cos(\theta_p) \\
 0 & \cos(\theta_y) & \sin(\theta_p) \sin(\theta_y)
\end{bmatrix} 
\pmatrix{ \dot{\theta}_y \\ \dot{\theta}_p \\ \dot{\theta}_r }
\;\tag{5}$$

Comment: Proof of the above comes from expanding the identity $ \dot{\mathrm{E}} = \vec{\omega} \times \mathrm{E}$ and the derivative product rule applied to the sequence of rotations in $\mathrm{E}$.

Comment: @fullnitrus - Equation (4) above is identical to your equation you posted in the comments.

Comment: I checked, equation (5) is identical to $$\begin{bmatrix} \omega_x \\ \omega_y \\ \omega_z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a\dot{\theta_p} - bc\dot{\theta_r} \\ \dot{\theta_y}+d\dot{\theta_r} \\b\dot{\theta_p} + ac\dot{\theta_r} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: "After the first rotation (yaw)"

Comment: I call it the first rotation because it is always about a fixed axis (the vertical). I come from robotics where kinematics are recursive from the base to the tip, and this is built in a similar fashion. I guess you would consider first the roll, then the pitch and the yaw, but for me it is logically arranged yaw-pitch-roll. The math is the same though.

Comment: yeah alright then sorry for getting confused.